# Owin self-host can not access via IP address

Tags: c#, owin

I use Owin to self host signalR and my simple html site.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
        var physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"./www");
        var options = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            FileSystem = physicalFileSystem
        };
        options.StaticFileOptions.FileSystem = physicalFileSystem;
        options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
        options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new[]
        {
            "index.html"
        };
        app.UseFileServer(options);
    }
```

Everything works fine except I can not access my website via local IP address such as 127.0.0.1.
When I navigate localhost:port, it works fine.
Note that all both I configure hosting via localhost or wildcard, I get same result.

```
string baseAddress = "http://*:80/";
```

My OS is Windows 10. What I tried:

- Using IP:port, hostname:port urls. All don't work.
- Disable firewall.
- Restart my PC.

Hope your helps!

Comment: Cleaner: localhost:port works; 127.0.0.1:port, wanip:port, hostname:port dont work.

Comment: If you want to add information to your question, you should [edit] it. You should never need to post a comment responding to your own posts.